# Prevent \setmathfont influence on \overline

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,mathtools}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \overline{\symup{X}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: screen]

The first result appears with second `\setmathfont` commented, and the second without. I don't understand why this second command affects the result, while its influence is normally limited to scr and bfscr.

Comment: Add `\setmathfont[range={}]{xits-math.otf}` after loading `latinmodern-math.otf` for the script letters.

Comment: Thx, working fine. How can I accept your answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known weakness of `unicode-math`: it takes several parameters for math typesetting from the last declared font. An easy workaround is to load again the main font with an empty range:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,mathtools}

\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={}]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[ \overline{\symup{X}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a weakness.  How is `unicode-math` supposed to know which font to take the parameters from?  Taking them from the font loaded last makes the most sense actually.  Otherwise you could never override the parameters again after loading the first font.

Comment: @HenriMenke There is `\setmathfont` without `range`: that should be the font where parameters are taken from. If I load a font just for the script letters, I surely *don't* want it takes over and break all the spacings.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  Sorry for being unclear.