# Brackets in maths text too large while using fira-math and TeX Gyre DejaVu Math combination in lualatex

Tags: luatex, tex-gyre-math

I am using fira-math and TeX Gyre DejaVu Math to typeset document using Lualatex.  I am using
TeX Gyre DejaVu Math since the arrow in fira-math seems too small.  I am using Arial for text.
As one can see from the output of the following mwe, the brackets I get using `\left(`, `\right)` combination are too large. I tried `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`. They only slightly better. How to rectify this problem? I have added a screenshot also.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
%the arrow from fira-math is too small.
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[Scale=1.8,range={\overrightarrow}]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]
\begin{document}
     The coordinates of A are $\left( a_1,a_2\right)$ and of B are $\left(b_1,b_2\right),$ then $\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|=\left|\overrightarrow{BA}\right|=\sqrt{{{\left(a_1-\ b_1\right)}^2+\left(a_2-b_2\right)}^2}$.
    %biggl biggr version
    
    \vskip 1cm
     The coordinates of A are $\biggl( a_1,a_2\biggr)$ and of B are $\biggl(b_1,b_2\biggr)$, then $\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|=\left|\overrightarrow{BA}\right|=\sqrt{{{\biggl(a_1-\ b_1\biggr)}^2+\biggl(a_2-b_2\biggr)}^2}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the output from traditional pdflatex for comparison.

[image]
In this `\left(` and `\right)` do the job perfectly.

Comment: Change `Scale=1.8` to a more reasonable `Scale=1.3` in the first `\setmathfont` directive, and most of the autosizing problems are gone. Get rid of the superfluous `{` and `}` instances inside the square root, and further issues (with the heights of the exponents) vanish as well.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. It worked.

Comment: @Mico Just curious.  I scaled only the arrow. Why did the brackets get scaled?

Comment: I can't help but take issue with your claim that `\left( and \right) do the job perfectly` under pdfLaTeX (but with the Arial and FiraMath OpenType fonts). While it's true that the parentheses are better under pdfLaTeX, they're not exactly perfect: Their associated parentheses are needlessly tall, and the horizontal spacing around them is still inappropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent \setmathfont influence on \overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421846/prevent-setmathfont-influence-on-overline) (Thanks, @Henri, for bringing this posing to my attention!)  Basically, after executing `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[Scale=1.8,range={\overrightarrow}]`, one has to run `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={}]` in order prevent the effect of `Scale=1.8` from propagating to further `\setmathfont` instructions.

Comment: @Mico Yes, it answers my questions.  The issue in my question was about brackets and the issue in this is different.  So, I missed it when I searched for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of (a) a multitude of unnecessary `\left` and `\right` directives and (b) a (likely) bug in the one or more of the opentype math fonts would appear to be the direct cause of the problem.

In the solution given below, I suggest four [4] improvements. They comprise getting rid of all `\left` and `\right` directives, getting rid of all unnecessary instances of `{` and `}`, and using a more reasonable value for the `Scale` option while loading a "special" form of the `\overrightarrow`. While steps 1 and 2 are the most important ones, steps 3 and 4 contribute useful improvements as well.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

%the arrow from fira-math is too small.
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[Scale=1.8,range={\overrightarrow}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]

\begin{document}

\noindent\textcolor{red}{OP's version}

The coordinates of A are $\left( a_1,a_2\right)$ 
and of B are $\left(b_1,b_2\right),$ then 
$\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|=
 \left|\overrightarrow{BA}\right|=
 \sqrt{{{\left(a_1-\ b_1\right)}^2+\left(a_2-b_2\right)}^2}.$


\bigskip\noindent\textcolor{red}{%
   1. Omit \texttt{\string\left} and \texttt{\string\right} around \texttt{|...|} expressions}

The coordinates of A are $\left( a_1,a_2\right)$ 
and of B are $\left(b_1,b_2\right),$ then 
$|\overrightarrow{AB}|=|\overrightarrow{BA}|=
 \sqrt{{{\left(a_1-\ b_1\right)}^2+\left(a_2-b_2\right)}^2}.$


\bigskip\noindent\textcolor{red}{%
   2. Fix Scaling of arrows}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[Scale=1.3,range={\overrightarrow}]

The coordinates of A are $\left( a_1,a_2\right)$ 
and of B are $\left(b_1,b_2\right),$ then 
$|\overrightarrow{AB}|=|\overrightarrow{BA}|=
 \sqrt{{{\left(a_1-\ b_1\right)}^2+\left(a_2-b_2\right)}^2}.$
 
 
\bigskip\noindent\textcolor{red}{%
   3. Omit superfluous instances of \texttt{\{} and \texttt{\}} in \texttt{\string\sqrt} term}

The coordinates of A are $\left( a_1,a_2\right)$ 
and of B are $\left(b_1,b_2\right),$ then 
$|\overrightarrow{AB}|=|\overrightarrow{BA}|=
 \sqrt{\left(a_1-b_1\right)^2+\left(a_2-b_2\right)^2}.$
 

\bigskip\noindent\textcolor{red}{%
   4. Get rid of all remaining \texttt{\string\left} and \texttt{\string\right} directives}

The coordinates of A are $(a_1,a_2)$ and of B are $(b_1,b_2)$, then 
$|\overrightarrow{AB}|=|\overrightarrow{BA}|=
 \sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2+(a_2-b_2)^2}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the massive overshoot in the paren size is due to reloading the font with `Scale=1.8,range={\overrightarrow}`. This seems to scale all the fontdimens by 1.8. When overriding parts of the font with `range` in the end the font should be reloaded with the desired global parameters and `range={}`. There should be some questions about this on the site, I'll see whether I can find something.

Comment: Ah yes, found one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421851/

Comment: @HenriMenke - Thanks! I've gone ahead and marked this posting as a dupe.