# Noto Sans Maths truetype font support for Unicode-maths

Tags: unicode-math, noto

I am looking for various unicode maths fonts to use with Arial. I have tried fira-math. But,
there are [problems in it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620778/brackets-in-maths-text-too-large-while-using-fira-math-and-tex-gyre-dejavu-math). So, I am looking for alternatives. Google has released Noto Sans Math font available [here](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Math). I tried this mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
\begin{document}
    \(\alpha\beta,\gamma\) This is a test.
\end{document}
```

It compiles without errors, but it quietly substitutes latin-modern for Noto Sans Math.  There is a warning in the log file which says

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "NotoSansMath-Regular" does not contain
(fontspec)                requested Script "Math".
```

I checked the font in microsoft word. It does have mathemtical symbols. So, what can be the problem? Curiously, the documentation for unicode-maths gives a list of fonts **that support** uncode-math not the other way around. Can anything be done, eg. using font forge, so that the font supports unicode-maths? How complicated is this to do?

Comment: the Math table does not refer to the characters provided but rather the internal table of that name that provides all the parameters needed for math typesetting. If a font does not have this then luatex/xetex will need the classic tex math font tfm metrics and can't be used with unicode-math

Comment: https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/330

Comment: note you could use fira math as the main math cont and still pull symbols from Moto sans see the range feature

Answer (score 8):

Illustrating @davidcarlisle's suggestion in the comments, about the `range=` option:

[image: halloween]

Blue is from Noto Sans Math.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Colour=brown]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=it/{latin,greek}]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=up/{num}]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,Colour=red]
\begin{document}
xyz
    \[x=f(y)_\alpha\beta,\gamma =\pumpkin(A)^{\mathghost}\] This is a test.
    \[\xrightflutteringbat[sin^{2}\theta]{sin\theta}\]
    \[ \overscriptrightbroom {a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{3}}\mathwitch* (\phi \minus\phi_{2}) \]
    \[ \mathcloud\greatpumpkin_{y=0}^{e^{i}} f(y_x) \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: use `\setmathfont{NotoSans-italic}[Colour=blue,range=it/{latin,greek}]` for actual sans italic, since the GoogleFonts download button only has NotoSansMath-Regular attached to it, with only a few operators and arrows (and Latin and Greek, upright not italic), not the full symbol set that Noto Sans has.