# Halloween and LateX

Tags: fonts, symbols

I got the idea of amusing my students by inserting some Halloween stuff in an assignment. Some searching gave me the `realhats` package, where `\hat{witch}{\text{Maple}}`, gave me Maple with a witch-hat over it. Nice indeed.

There is https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/luatex/latex/emoji/emoji-doc.pdf which contains an ogre, a goblin and a ghost.

And there is [www.myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/search?query=Halloween). They are good, but rather expensive for a one time amusement.

Isn't there something more? Maybe somebody can suggest a font, some smileys, a package with Halloween-oriented stuff.

Comment: `webdings` is another example

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath, but isn't Halloween over for this time?

Comment: Well, Halloween is over. And the assignment was sent to the students. But maybe I can use it for next year.
Thank you for the suggestions. They are perfect. Is there any way to "close" the subject as solved? Or is it better to leave it open?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620788/halloweenmath-contest-in-memory-of-gum