# How to write Odia in LaTeX?

Tags: unicode, languages, indic

I want to write an article in [Odia language.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odia_language)
Some kind people in the TeX chat room helped me.  Now I'm using this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Oriya,
  BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=600}}},
  BoldFont=*
]{NotoSansOriya-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf}
\begin{document}
"ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ |"\\
{\bfseries
"ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ|"}\\
"My name is Kalia, No one is like me."

$$a^2+b^2=c^2, କ^2+b^୨ =c^2$$
\end{document}
```

And this gives [image: output]
To write my article I only need to know how to change the font typeface of English text of entire document.

Though this is not that necessary for my article, But I am curious to see how to

1. write Odia letters in italics
2. use Odia letters in math-mode.

I tried but Odia letters doesn't appear in math-mode. In the image see that the letter 'କ' is not appearing in math-mode but the number '୨' appears.

Lastly, Is there any other way to write Odia in LaTeX?

Thank you.

PNDas

Comment: I can't see any odia font with italic, is that used at all really? The script looks so scarily regular is it ever used in slanted form? you could use unicode-math package to add the Odia font for the appropriate unicode range in math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't know. I think, I have seen it in school textbooks. I actually don't remember. I was just curious .

Comment: In MS Word, you can use italic Odia. But tbh, that looks awful.

Comment: Word will just apply a geometrical transformation to any character (which is what autofakeslant does in the posted answer), but culturally does it make sense, is that used in real tradition in your region?

Comment: I found some typefaces in Odia. https://www.cdac.in/index.aspx?id=pdf_Oriya_OT_fonts . But don't know how to download them.

Comment: If those fonts are freely available (or you buy them) and you install in your operating system, you will be able to use them from lualatex. Basically if you are on Windows you can use any font you can use in Word

Comment: As to combining fonts for different scripts, you can do it without explicit markup (with `lualatex`). Take a look at `combofont` or at `babel`, which supports Odia (named in former versions `oriya`, but in the current one `odia`). If this is of interest for you, I can prepare an answer.

Comment: @JavierBezos, please add an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use different fonts for different scripts so use real italic for Latin and no italic (or fake slant) for Odia

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\odia[
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Oriya,
  BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=600}}},
  BoldFont=*
]{NotoSansOriya-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf}
\begin{document}
{\odia"ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ |"}

{\odia\bfseries
"ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ|"}

``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''

{\itshape ``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''}

{\bfseries ``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''}

\[a^2+b^2=c^2, \text{\odia କ}^2+b^{\text{\odia ୨}} =c^2\]

\end{document}
```

In comments you said you wanted to keep latin modern, so do not change the main font and use thiner Odia fonts as the default weight is too heavy
alongside LM

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\odia[
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Oriya,
  RawFeature={axis={wght=300}},
  BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=500}}},
  BoldFont=*
]{NotoSansOriya-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf}
\begin{document}
{\odia"ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ |"}

{\odia\bfseries
"ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ|"}

``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''

{\itshape ``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''}

{\bfseries ``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''}

\[a^2+b^2=c^2, \text{\odia କ}^2+b^{\text{\odia ୨}} =c^2\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used Noto Sans and Noto sans Oriya here but you do not have to use "related" families choose any that you consider to match

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I wanted to change the typeface of English text. Normally I use Latin modern. Is it possible to change the English text to Latin modern?

Comment: Latin modern is the default in lualatex, so simply delete the line `\setmainfont{Noto Sans}` @PNDas

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I'm asking so many questions. If I want to change the fonts then do I need to put \setmainfont{name_of_the_font}?

Comment: @PNDas see updated answer. (fontspec has a manual: `texdoc fontspec` or learnlatex has examples of this)

Answer (score 5):

As to the text fonts, here is an example with `babel` showing how to switch the font with the script (and the hyphenation rules, too). Actually, this example can serve as a model for other Indic languages, including Assamese, Gujarati, Hindi, Kannada, Malayalam, Tamil, etc. I presume you actually want a danda instead of a vertical bar, so I’ve replaced it. I’ve added some explanations as comments.

Note, however, you will find always ambiguous situations requiring explicit markup, as the quotes reveal in this example. No universal rules can be settled and depends largely on the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

% In versions >=3.79 the preferred name is odia. In previous versions
% use oriya. Although languages are usually passed as options to babel,
% in this case I’ll use \babelprovide to activate a useful transform,
% which prevents a break before a danda if preceded by a space.

\babelprovide[
  import, main,
  % mapdigits, % Optional: replace Arabic digits by Odia ones
  transforms = danda.nobreak]{odia}

% Tell babel to switch the font and hyphenation when a char
% of the script for English (ie, the Latin script) is found.

\babelprovide[onchar = ids fonts]{english}

% By default, digits and puntuation are considered part of the Latin
% script. Very likely that’s wrong and have to be fixed in babel, but
% fortunately there is a workaround:

\babelcharproperty{`\!}[`\@]{locale}{odia}
\babelcharproperty{`\[}[`\`]{locale}{odia}
\babelcharproperty{`\{}[`\}]{locale}{odia}

% Set the main roman font, for the main language. 'Script' and
% 'Language' are set by babel. You may find a nasty and somewhat
% misleading warning about language and/or script not found raised by
% fontspec - just ignore it (it will be concealed altogether in babel
% 3.81):

\babelfont{rm}
  [Renderer=HarfBuzz,
   BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=600}}},
   BoldFont=*
  ]{NotoSansOriya-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf}

% Set the font for english:

\babelfont[english]{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}

ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ ।

``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.'' 

\textit{``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''}

\textbf{``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''}

\textbf{ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ ।}

\end{document}
```

[image: Odia]

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SX! The font you choose does not come with italics, so you may want to choose a font that actually provides italic letters (given that such a typographic feature even exists in this script). It may not be too appealing typographically, but if you still want to stick with NotoSans Oriya, you can use the `AutoFakeSlant` option provided by `fontspec` which will fake italics by slanting the glyphs.

As for the use in math mode, you may want to wrap the letters in a `\text` macro which will typeset the non-italic style of the relevant glyph.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,
  Script=Oriya,
  BoldFeatures={RawFeature={axis={wght=600}}},
  BoldFont=*,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.2
]{NotoSansOriya-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf}

\begin{document}
``ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ |''

{\bfseries
``ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ|''}

``My name is Kalia, No one is like me.''

{\itshape
``ନାଆଁଟି ମୋର କାଳିଆ, କେହି ନାହିଁ ମୋ ଭଳିଆ|''}

\[a^2+b^2=c^2, \text{କ}^2+b^\text{୨} =c^2\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What about changing the fonts of English letters?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/620779/47927) regarding how to set up NotoSans for math mode. However, I fear that you cannot use the variable font in math mode.

Comment: I was talking about the font of English text of whole document. Usually I use latin modern package. But this cancels fontspec.

Comment: @PNDas So, you mean you only want NotoSans Oriya for the Oriya glyphs?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. \\\\\

Comment: @PNDas Then David Carlile's approach is probably better suited.

Comment: @JasperHabicht The variable font should also work in math mode, just add the `axis` feature like in the text font.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger This may be true, but I have already problems in setting up something like `\setmathfont{NotoSansOriya-Regular}[range={"0B00-"0B4D}]` which does not work at all, which I don't understand.