# How can unicode-math and halloweenmath be used together?

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I'm trying to use the packages `unicode-math` and `halloweenmath` together, and I've found [another response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620813/187636) giving an example showing the two packages working together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Colour=brown]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=it/{latin,greek}]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=up/{num}]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,Colour=red]
\begin{document}
xyz
\[x=f(y)_\alpha\beta,\gamma =\pumpkin(A)^{\mathghost}\] This is a test.
\[\xrightflutteringbat[sin^{2}\theta]{sin\theta}\]
\[ \overscriptrightbroom {a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{3}}\mathwitch* (\phi \minus\phi_{2}) \]
\[ \mathcloud\greatpumpkin_{y=0}^{e^{i}} f(y_x) \]

\end{document}
```

However, when I compile this example, the symbols provided by `halloweenmath` are "blown out":

[image: Compiled example, showing blown out halloween math symbols, while the rest of the example works fine]

When I remove the unicode-math package, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage{halloweenmath}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \setmathfont{Asana Math}[Colour=brown]
% \setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=it/{latin,greek}]
% \setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=up/{num}]
% \setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,Colour=red]
\begin{document}
xyz
\[x=f(y)_\alpha\beta,\gamma =\pumpkin(A)^{\mathghost}\] This is a test.
\[\xrightflutteringbat[sin^{2}\theta]{sin\theta}\]
\[ \overscriptrightbroom {a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{3}}\mathwitch* (\phi \minus\phi_{2}) \]
\[ \mathcloud\greatpumpkin_{y=0}^{e^{i}} f(y_x) \]

\end{document}
```

The symbols show up fine:

[image: Correct example with normal halloweenmath symbols]

Have these packages been updated to be incompatible since that answer was made, or is there something wrong with the configuration on my machine?

Comment: `halloweenmath` uses `\fontdimen` parameters that are (unfortunately) computed wrongly with XeLaTeX and make no sense whatsoever with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Interesting, I had thought that lualatex was meant to be the "main version" of latex going forward. Kind of weird that it doesn't work with this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It can be patched for LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The `halloweenmath` package is evidently a one-off project, posted in 2017 with an update shortly thereafter. Evidently its creator did not intend it to be a lifetime project, or one that can be used in all circumstances. Many TeX packages are like that, because many TeX packages are the work of a user who has shared something useful, and then moves on. Evidently this package creator was not using LuaLaTeX at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `halloweenmath` package uses `\fontdimen` parameters that make no sense with `unicode-math` and LuaLaTeX. But it can be patched.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{iftex}

\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Colour=brown]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=it/{latin,greek}]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf}[Colour=blue,range=up/{num}]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,Colour=red]

\ifluatex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@HwM@thickness@units@for[1]{%
  \expandafter\Umathfractiondenomvgap\expanded{\style@from@font{#1}}%
}
\def\style@from@font#1{%
  \ifx#1\textfont\textstyle\else
  \ifx#1\scriptfont\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\xpatchcmd{\@HwM@math@picture}
  {\fontdimen 22 #4\tw@}
  {\expandafter\Umathaxis\expanded{\style@from@font{#4}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@HwM@stylefont@arrowfill}
  {\fontdimen 6 #4\tw@}
  {\expandafter\Umathquad\expanded{\style@from@font{#4}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@HwM@init@swish@dimens}
  {\fontdimen 22 #1\tw@}
  {\expandafter\Umathaxis\expanded{\style@from@font{#1}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\fi


\begin{document}

xyz
\[x=f(y)_\alpha\beta,\gamma =\pumpkin(A)^{\mathghost}\] This is a test.
\[\xrightflutteringbat[\sin^{2}\theta]{\sin\theta}\]
\[ \overscriptrightbroom {a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{3}}\mathwitch* (\phi \minus\phi_{2}) \]
\[ \mathcloud\greatpumpkin_{y=0}^{e^{i}} f(y_x) \]

\end{document}
```

This runs as expected with LuaLaTeX. Something is not really precise with XeLaTeX that computes some font dimensions incorrectly.

#### Output with LuaLaTeX

[image]

#### Output with XeLaTeX

[image]

You can see that the ghost is not the same.

Comment: excellent outcome, you do the work, and I get the tick.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 

Answer (score 4):

You can use xelatex rather than lualatex

[image]

Comment: That is unfortunate that LuaLatex doesn't work with this, but you are correct, xelatex works fine.

Comment: @OttovonBisquick it could be fixed for luatex I may add something later if no one else does

Comment: @OttovonBisquick oh egreg has done that already,